# rogue process started by sec sending hundreds of mails

Tags: debian, exim

I started a sec process via

```
/etc/init.d/sec start
```

with a bad config file (the arguments being passed are in an unintended format.

When a rule passes it tries to mail me. If the mail script dies, it mails me saying that the mail script dies.

I am getting hundreds of mails from something having to do with this process... I found a sec process via

```
ps auxw | grep sec
```

and killed it.

The script that mails me is called mailsec.sh. I moved that file so it could no longer be executed.

```
ps auxw | grep mailsec.sh
```

does not show anything either.

However, I am still getting emails and the load average on the server is really high. Any ideas on how to debug this?

Tried running the following commands to see what was in the queue. I cleared the queue a few minutes ago, so notihgn should be showing up and indeed, nothing is:

```
root@localhost:/var/log# exim4 -bp
root@localhost:/var/log# mailq
root@localhost:/var/log#
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your queue with `mailq`, maybe you have too many messages queued for delivery and it will take some time. You can use `exim4 -Mrm <id>` to remove a message from the queue, so if you grep the correct IDs for the messages you don't want you can remove it with a `for` loop like this:

```
mailq |grep root | awk '{ print $3}' | xargs exim4 -Mrm
```

Just notice that in this case I am grepping `root` so it will remove any message that was sent by root, YMMV.

Comment: updated my question. seems as if there is nothing in the queue.

Comment: Well I failed... had to restart :( Thanks a ton though for your input, it was much appreciated!